# How to use getStats api

Tags: javascript, node.js, webrtc, puppeteer

I am using Puppeteer headless browser and doing WebRTC call. At the end of call I want to know statistics like bandwidth, Jitter, ICE details etc.

So far what I have been able to collect from google search is we can get the stats data using getStats api.

But in a puppeteer script how I can call getStats api, I could not find any example.

My code looks as below.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const sleep = (waitTimeInMs) => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, waitTimeInMs));

(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false});
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('https://janus.conf.meetecho.com/videocalltest.html');
    await page.waitForSelector('#start');
    await page.click('[id=start]');
    await page.waitForSelector('#username', { visible: true });
    await page.type('input[id="username"]', 'user1');
    await page.click('button[id=register]');
    await page.waitFor(5000);
    await page.type('input[id=peer]', 'user0');
    await page.click('button[id=call]');
    await sleep(16000);
    await page.click('button[id=start]');
    await sleep(3000);
    await browser.close();
})();
```

Just before browser.close(), I want to know stats data. Can you please help me to understand, how can I make use of getStats api in this context to get the stats data.

Is there any better way to get stats data then getsStats api?

Comment: Can't you call  `evaluate` and get that with a script?

Comment: @hardkoded, sorry I am not an expert, can you please give one example

Comment: How and where are you accepting the 2nd call? Also I am not pretty sure but WebRTC may not even work in a headless mode, which means the call may not even work, have you verified that first?

Comment: Yes, webrtc call is working. I am able to call getStats(), but it's returning blank.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `evaluate` to get the WebRTC stats:

```js
result = await page.evaluate(async () => await videocall.webrtcStuff.pc.getStats());
console.log(result);
```

Comment: I get error "=>Error: Evaluation failed: TypeError: Cannot read property 'webrtcStuff' of null". In my case, its a headless browser. How do I get videocall object?

Comment: the code looks as here, __stats = await page.evaluate(() => videocall.webrtcStuff.pc.getStats());

Comment: You'd need to check what's the object you have with the webrtc client you want to get the stats from. When I checked your page `videocall` was not null.

Comment: I am sorry, how can I check the object. Request if you can help me to understand how do I find the videocall object and its members.

Comment: I got the object details now. Looks videocall.webrtcStuff.pc is fine. But why it says Cannot read property 'webrtcStuff' of null", I am not getting it.

Comment: now I am able to call getStats(). It returns blank {}. What may be the reason?

Comment: Could it be getStats is returning some circular json?